# Quotient Groups: Computational Implementation

Tags: group-theory

For a permutation group $G$ and subgroup $H$, what is the best way to calculate $G/H = J$ computationally?

If we store each permutation as a row in matrix ${\bf G}$ and similarly for ${\bf H}$, I have the following Matlab implementation:

```
J = []                    
while isempty(G) == 0        
    J = [J; G(1,:)]; 
    temp = G(1,:);

    %Now delete all right coset values H*G(1,:) in G
    for i = 1:length(H(:,1))
        temp2 = H(i,:);
        [~,indx] = ismember(temp2(temp),G,'rows');
        G(indx,:) = [];    
    end
end
```

Unfortunately this is very slow for permutation groups of order $\geq 8$. Is there a better way?

Comment: A literature survey of better ways is in http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/3-540-54955-2_38

Comment: Section 4.6.7 of Derek Holt's Handbook covers this as well.